# How to capture bounce email in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails

Is there a way where i can capture the email that bounced after the user registration and create a script to block that account?

Answer (score 4):

One way to disallow bogus e-mails is to validate them during registration process. There are quite few extensions and guides available by simple Google search 'joomla validate email', such as [Pre Registration Email Validation plugin](http://www.function90.com/products/pre-registration-email-validation.html) or [Client-side form validation guide](https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation).

There is also another approach for bounce-handling used in commercial newsletter extensions like [Acymailing Enterprise](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/120-acymailing-bounce.html#what) and [RSMail](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsmail-user-guide/getting-started-/rsmail-settings.html), which are able to handle such messages and execute actions on wrong receiver such as Delete the user, Block the user etc.

But, writing such a 'script' as you are asking for, requires significant knowledge, experience and a price tag, and I am afraid it exceeds scope of such Q&A site as JSE is.